How to create global secondary index GSI using amplify gen 2 models?
In amplify gen1, there are ways to define GSI as documented here:
https://docs.amplify.aws/gen1/react/tools/cli-legacy/key-directive/#deploying-multiple-secondary-indices-gsi
However, in amplify gen2, I don't see any way to define GSI
Local indexes can be defined as documented here:
https://docs.amplify.aws/react/build-a-backend/data/data-modeling/secondary-index/
Custom queries can be defined as documented here:
https://docs.amplify.aws/react/build-a-backend/data/data-modeling/secondary-index/
There is a mention of GSI here but nothing on how to create them:
https://docs.amplify.aws/react/build-a-backend/data/override-resources/
However, there does not seem to be any canonical way of creating GSI. Am I missing something?
